# Is it possible to validate multiple input fields with setCustomValidity?

Tags: javascript, html

I have

```
<form>
  <input id="input1" required>...</input>
  <input id="input2">...</input>
  <input id="input3">...</input>
</form>
```

and I need to validate that `input2 + input3 === 100`.

I'd like to do it using `setCustomValidity` (the form is much more complex and I've been using `setCustomValidity` everywhere, and this is the last validation I have left to implement).

I think `setCustomValidity` can be applied to a single `input` element, but I'd like to apply it to a combination of inputs. Is there any way? Something like

```
<form>
  <input id="input1" required>...</input>
  <div APPLY setCustomValidity AT THIS LEVEL>
    <input id="input2">...</input>
    <input id="input3">...</input>
  </div>
</form>
```

or using any other combining element instead of a `div`...?

Comment: Could you just leave one field editable and the other is calculated by `100 - value` so that you don't need to check both values? or you could perhaps replace it by a horizontal slider.

Comment: Not really. As I mentioned, the form is much more complex. The number of inputs is dynamic (up to 20 fields), and they all have to be positive. If I automatically fill the last one, depending on the values the user has introduced, I might get a negative number, which wouldn't make sense either... Thank you for the idea though!

Comment: You answer somehow gave me a nice idea: I *do* have a `div` that shows the actual sum. I could change this `div` into a `readonly` input and make the validation against this field...¿?¿? Let's see if it works!

Comment: Just a suggestion, It can also be achieved by the jquery or javscript. you can write a function to do the validations for you. everytime you need it just call it !

Comment: Why do you want to use setCustomValidity for validation, I thought checkValidity() was used for validation, maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Maybe use some script to check for what you want? Something like this:            
            function validateInput() {
                if ($('#input2').val() + $('#input3').val() !== '100') {
                   $('#input2').setCustomValidity("Please enter correct value")
       $('#input3').val().setCustomValidity("Please enter correct value")                  
                } else {
                   $('#input2').setCustomValidity('')
    $('#input2').setCustomValidity('')  //do something else below
                }
            }
            $('#formID').click(validateInput)

Comment: @ajinkya, yes I use javascript, but I use `checkValidity` to check if the form is valid (and enable the submit button). Therefore, I need to set a custom validity with `setCustomValidity` somehow. Can I use `checkValidity` with a custom js function without using `setCustomValidity`?

Comment: @SachinYadav: when `checkValidity` is executed, it checks if the default validations (required, pattern, min, max, ...) are satisfied *and* if there is a custom validity. Your custom validation can be checked with a function you create and you have to report the result with the `setCustomValidity` (if I'm not wrong). In my case, I need a non standard validation. I create it on my own and I add it with `setCustomValidity` so that when I execute `checkValidity` it tells if the form is valid or not (at least, this is what I understood...).

Comment: @Jeff: yes, I have the function, but I need to add the validation somehow so that `checkValidity` works. See the comments above...

Comment: I think you're asking two different questions now, first you want to apply `setCustomValidity` on a combination of input fields - that is possible through the JS code I provided above, next you want to add validation for `checkValidity` with that all you need to do is add `required` to all input fields or like this: `required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter your custom error message')"`  because when `checkValidity` is executed, all it does is that it checks if the default validations (required, pattern, min, max) are satisfied. so not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: @Jeff: sorry, I after I wrote the other comments I forgot you actually used the `setCustomValidity`. The thing is that I want to apply it to the group, not to each element individually. However, if I add the custom validity (forget about the `required`) is precisely because I'll check `checkValidity` afterwards (if a custom validity is not the empty string, `checkValidity` will fail as expected).